# What could result in a colonized Mars setting up a monarchy

Tags: science-fiction, government, planets

**In the future after a nuclear war has ravaged Earth, leaving the Martian colonies on their own and without support...**

Mars falls under the attacks of local militias, fragmenting. That is until some brave individual, their first empress to be, through some happenstance leads the broken Martian people, unites them, and sets them on the path to peace. After a long fought conflict, roaming bands of fighters, terrorists and bandits driven back, a united Mars now is on the way to crowning this girl.

---

This element is in the background of a story I'm working on. In the beginning the Martian colonies were multinational and administered by each nation until the war. The Empress to be was a symbol of the fight and rebellion, beloved by the people. But she didn't seek to be anything more than a fighter.

By the present in this universe the Martians are definitely a nearly absolute monarchy.

The question is: why would they be willing and all set to bring about a new monarchy?

**EDIT**

I'm very,very sorry about last time. I'll rephrase the question and try to keep the answers relevant.

The monarchy is constitutional at first and then progresses closer to absolute.

Under what conditions could a Martian people or new government replace their old government with a monarchy?

Comment: I apologize, but this question is the essence of what it means to be too story-based.  This site is dedicated to building your world, its rules and systems, not your story and its circumstances.  And it reflects the simplest method of detecting an OT:TSB question: it's asking to justify a choice or action rather than a consequence or rule.

Comment: It began how all [medieval monarchies began](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merovingian_dynasty). Some people specialized in offering protection services. Eventually the leader of one of those protection rackets became paramount leader. Initially the position is elective, but eventually it becomes hereditary. As in plain ordinary European history, the nascent monarchy may evolve towards a weak German-style position or towards an absolutist French-like position. (Hint: the [Star Kingdom of Manticore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honorverse) and the Protectorate of Grayson.)

Comment: The only possible answer, to a story based question like this, is ***why wouldn't they??***

Comment: Apart from being too story based, note that there are [different types of monarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monarchy).  Each of these would have different driving forces behind them.

Comment: Same way a lot of monarchies started, a war leader was made king by his army so that power was contained, any other form of govt would dissipate control at a critical time and impact on both the monarchs and the senior vassals safety. Once the fighting is done, they expect rewards not insecurity..

Comment: @elemtilas Sorry, Sorry! I Wasn't thinking there. I'm new and all I'll edit it as soon as possible.

Comment: This is not asking about a story plot but how to establish a government considering that monarchy is an old form of government unlikely to become Mars new government. I don't see this question as story based just because the author is writing a story.

Answer (score 3):

**"Democracy is the worst form of government..."**

Assumption 1: Mars was settled primarily by the Western democracies.

Corollary:  Mars had only experienced a democratic form of government prior to the Earth apocalypse.

Assumption 2:  Studying Earth history was considered "unfashionable" by the Martian colonists.  This is a side-effect of trying to establish a Martian planetary/national identity.  So the general populace and even the intelligentsia are not familiar with Winston Churchill's address to the House of Commons on 11 November 1947:

> ...No one pretends that democracy is perfect or all-wise. Indeed it
>   has been said that democracy is the worst form of Government except
>   for all those other forms that have been tried from time to time.…

Assumption 3:  The democratic government failed miserably at managing events prior to and immediately after the Earth apocalypse, as evidenced by the fact there were militias out there.  Not to mention that there may have been other, far more mundane mismanagement - even when not under immediate threat, some wealthy democracies are not even able to pay their own government workers for weeks at a time (not mentioning any names!)

Consequence:  As far as the population of Mars was concerned, democracy was an utter failure.  Swift, decisive action was required to deal with their problems and the democratic government was not up to the job, *but the empress-to-be was*.  As a result, the populace went with what works and made themselves an empire.

I suggest that even the most fanatic anti-democrats would want some safeguards against an emperor / empress who went completely bonkers or evil.  One possibility would be for an "impeachment and removal" option by popular vote, remembering that technology of today or higher makes electronic voting feasible.  Make it such that if the ruler survives one vote then another cannot be brought for at least a year (Martial or otherwise) and provide some other negative consequences for a failed vote so that one is not initiated trivially.

Answer (score 1):

**Tradition** --- *Apologies if this changes your lore.*

The [conquest of Mars](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0888496/), and its subsequent [colonization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron_Sky), was made by a dictatorship as a result of its boastful [race to space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Race). [At first it was just a military base](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mir#Origins). Then, [entire villages were relocated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_conquest_of_Siberia#Conquest_and_exploration), to [show the progress, might and resilience](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2018/jan/07/china-move-millions-people-homes-anti-poverty-drive) of the said dictatorship.

Meanwhile on Earth...
[A terrible war between the coalition of dictatorships and the non-dictatorships ravaged all the continents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_War_II), leaving Mars alone. The locals, lost contact with Earth, and [believing that the war continued](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-asia-25772192), preserved their way of living and, most of all, their ridicoulous bureaucracy. [Unsurprisingly, from the ranks of the local administration there finally emerged the special office of Martian Dictator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_Stalin#Rise_to_power). While initially based on a democratic vote, the office turned into a hereditary absolutist monarchy.

Answer (score 0):

**To Use as a Puppet**

The revolutionaries needed a useful figurehead to symbolize not only something martian born, but something brave, righteous, and independent of the now hopeless earth below. The new government needed unity to prevent falling to chaos again. A shiny underdog hero rising up with their own strength could be something that a disheartened martian people would need after their abandonment by the earth.

She as a fighter made a convenient puppet for the cause after some daring, inspiring or game-changing action.

After coronation, like in most current monarchies, she serves to galvanize the people and nothing more while prime minister and parliament work to run things.

Comment: Although I like this idea, it does run into the problem of how to go from figurehead empress to an absolute monarchy by the "present day".